# iOS: data disappear after passing it to another ViewController

Tags: ios, properties, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I have a problem in my app.
When I pass a UIView to a SecondViewController in this way

```
SecondViewController *second = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondviewcontroller"];
second.currentView = currentView;
```

(second.currentView is my property in SecondViewController and I pass to it my view)

At this point, it's all ok and my SecondViewController show correctly my currentView, but when I retund in FirstViewController my currentView disappear!!!
Why? Can you help me? thanks

**UPDATE**

in FirstViewController.h

```
IBOutlet UIView *currentView;
```

in FirstViewController.m

```
SecondViewController *second = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondviewcontroller"];
second.currentView = currentView;
[self presentViewController:second animated:NO completion:nil];
```

in SecondViewController.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *currentView;
```

in SecondViewController.m

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[self.view addSubview:self.currentView];
self.currentView.center = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2,   self.view.bounds.size.height/2);
}
```

this is my code in the two ViewControllers, and when I return in FirstViewController currentView there isn't... it disappear...

Comment: yes, I use dismissViewController

Comment: I think that the best solution is to use a global var in appDelegate and in this way I solve all my problems

Comment: I tried, it don't solve my problem

Comment: it's simply [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil]; inside an IBAction

Answer (score 0):

A view only have super view, so when you add the view to `SecondViewController` you care adding it to its view hierarchy and thus removing to from your current view controller. When you call something like:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Here the view is removed the first view and placed on the second view.
    [self.view addSubView:self.secondView];
}
```

Thus if you want to add it back in the first view you need to add it again to view hierarchy of the first view.

A **beter** solution would be pass the data to the next view controller, not to view but the model. Like pass the model object holding the data presented in the view.

Comment: can you make me an example?

Comment: No since I've have no idea about the data you are try to share between the two view controllers. Also you should try to solve the issue your self.

Comment: This answer is correct, when u set the view of the first view controller to the second controller u are removing it from the first one. Furthermore, passing a view is a weird thing so u might try to explain what exactly are you trying to do.

Answer (score -1):

I solved my issue!!!

When I return in FirtsViewController I must add a new time my view in my self.view at last position, in this way:

```
[self.view addSubview:currentView];

[currentView setCenter:initially_center_view];
```

in this way I see my view!!!